# are there character set restrictions or autoconversion oddities for location.hash?

Tags: javascript, url, location

i want to store and retrieve data via the url hash. the user is able to make some dropdown settings on the page, which should get written into the url via the `location.replace` function*.

for simplicity’s sake, it now works like this: initially, the user is on `test.com`. after changing two settings, the url looks like this: `http://test.com#fruit→banana#color→light blue`.

another almost as simple way would be `http://test.com#fruit=banana, color=light blue`. the only characters the settings and options contain are (as regular expression) `[A-Za-z &]`

as far as i can tell, this works fine, although firefox url-escapes everything on copying, and chrome doesn’t. after pasting and pressing enter, the url bar shows the unescaped hash, fetching `location.hash` per javascript also gives the unescaped unicode string.

my question: are there any probblems, inconsistencies, or other quirks i don’t know about?

---

*FYI: `location.replace("#hash")` works just like one would expect :D

Comment: `location.hash` does not work the same way across browsers when reading the value, so beware. If you wish to read the value of the hash crossbrowser look at `location.href` and ignore everything before the hash :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i already noted in the comment, forget

```
location.hash
```

and use

```
location.href.replace(/^[^#]+/,'');
```

instead.

It will save you a whole heap of trouble.

Comment: but otherwise, there is no restriction on what characters to use in the hash?

Comment: Tbh i don't know - i have never run into restrictions, but on the other hand it doesn't mean there aren't any. It probably depends on what browsers you need to support - i would guess ie6 has other restrictions than chrome 13 - testing is the way to go :)

Comment: well, after some testing i found that the classic `#setting=option&other setting=other option` works.